# Use preloaded database with Realm and RealmMapView using Swift 2.1

Tags: realm, swift2

Using Swift 2.0 with Realm, is it possible to specify the database to use with RealmMapView?

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myDB", ofType: "realm")

var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
config.path = path

self.mapView.realmConfiguration = config
```

This currently works on the Simulator, but not on the device.

Answer (score 0):

On device the application's bundle is read-only, so you have to set `config.readOnly = true` to open the Realm in read-only mode.